# How to dynamically make TextView's setVisibility(View.GONE)?

Tags: android

I am displaying a List that contains 3 Textview for name, start_date and day.Now I want that if any start_date value is empty, Listview must not display that TextView. I know the functionality of "GONE". But In my case I am using hashmap. I don't know where to apply "GONE".

Here is my code:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, hashList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME,
                        TAG_START_DATE, TAG_DAYS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.startdate, R.id.days });
```

Here `R.id.name`, `R.id.startdate`, `R.id.days` are `Textview`s.
Here, start_date may and may not be available, so `R.id.startdate` must be applied `Visibility` `Gone` if hashmap don't has value for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own adapter, extending `BaseAdapter` for instance. Then, when the `getView()` callback is called you can check your condition and show the info accordingly

Comment: Why not extending `SimpleAdapter` , overriding only `getView()` with a call to `super.getView()` and modify the visibility of the TextView when needed?

Comment: Why not, mine was only an example/suggestion.

Comment: I always use `BaseAdapter`. There are always chances that when you add complexity to your app, `SimpleAdapter` cannot satisfy the layout needs anymore. You will have to rewrite everything again. Just my opinion though :p

Comment: @LawrenceChoy mine as well